# setup a specific regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm new at Python and I need a regular expression to retrieve the title and the link of this format:

```
<a href="anything" class="anything" title="Size: anything">anything</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2032663

Comment: Except of course that you wouldn't be trying to parse HTML with regex, would you? No-one would do that :-)

Comment: The reason you're getting downvoted isn't that the question itself is badly written.  Rather, the very presence of this question shows a lack of prior research on your part; This question is asked/answered a thousand times.  HTML is not regular, and hence Regex is not the right technology to handle it.  Further, you haven't given an indication of what you've actually tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd be much better off using a decent HTML Parser. Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which has [extensive documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) - for example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(input)

for link in soup.find_all('a', class_='anything'):
    print link['href'], link.text
```

This finds all `<a>` elements with the class `anything`, then prints their URL and link text.

Regular expressions are usually *not* the tool for parsing HTML.

Comment: It is not parsing Guys I just need to retrieve General Infos. and not specific anything = any string and not "anything" but itself

Comment: @MennouchiAzeddineIslam: This is an *example*. You can easily adjust it to your specific situation. Remove the `class_='anything'` filter for example. And yes, you have a parsing task at hand.

Comment: Thank You just one more question and for the title field how can I do that I mean title="Size: anything"

Comment: @MennouchiAzeddineIslam: `link['title']`. I linked to the BeautifulSoup website, there is excellent documentation there to be found.